# Why is `print -P "%%"` behaviour different within library function?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

On my terminal:

```
$ print -P "%%"
%
```

The equivalent code within a [Spaceship prompt](https://spaceship-prompt.sh/) function:

```
spaceship_extension() {
  unset PROMPT_PERCENT 
  unset PROMPT_SUBST
  print -P "00%%\n"

  set PROMPT_PERCENT 
  unset PROMPT_SUBST
  print -P "01%%\n"
  
  unset PROMPT_PERCENT 
  set PROMPT_SUBST
  print -P "10%%\n"
  
  set PROMPT_PERCENT
  set PROMPT_SUBST
  print -P "11%%\n"
}
```

Output:

```
00
01
10
11
```

According to the [Prompt Expansion man page](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html), those are the only relevant environment variables. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Edit: Removed `exports` that were obviating the setting and resetting of the environment variables.

Comment: You aren't setting or unsetting any of the options; you are just exporting a bunch of parameter names.

Comment: That is, you are exporting the names `set` and `unset`, not executing the `set` and `unset` commands.

Comment: @chepner, that's for the pointer. The result is the same if I remove the exports. But I added them in the service of trying to be extra sure that the code in `print` sees the changes. But it's all in the same process so that shouldn't be an issue anyway, right?

Comment: I don't know how you managed to eliminate the `%` altogether from the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that `export` has no effect on either option; you are just setting the export attribute on a set of names in each case.

Second, `set` and `unset` operate on names, not shell options. You want `setopt` and `unsetopt`.

```
% setopt PROMPT_PERCENT
% print -P '00%%\n'
00%

% unsetopt PROMPT_PERCENT
% print -P '00%%\n'
00%%
```

(In practice, unsetting `PROMPT_PERCENT` may affect your actual prompt; I used `%` here as a placeholder for the prompt, not an accurate representation of what you prompt may look like after unsetting the option.)